# Formatting and printing a two-dimensional array (VB6)

Tags: arrays, vb6

I need help here in a multiplication table program. The program asks the user through a text box the dimension of the two-dimensional array. When the dimension is retrieved, the program should print the multiplication table with the given dimension neatly in the form. The problem is, I do not know how to print the array neatly in a table format. It's something like this as a sample output:

```
1 2  3  4  5 
2 4  6  8  10
3 6  9  12 15
4 8  12 16 20
5 10 15 20 25
```

Here's my work.

```
Option Explicit

Dim maxNum As Integer
Dim multiplicationTable() As Integer
Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer

Private Sub cmdDisplay_Click()

    cmdDisplay.Enabled = False
    maxNum = Val(txtDimension.Text)

    ReDim multiplicationTable(maxNum, maxNum) As Integer

    For y = 1 To maxNum
        For x = 1 To maxNum
            multiplicationTable(x, y) = x * y
        Next x
    Next y

End Sub
```

What piece of code could make this program print the table neatly in the form?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will print the table exactly as you show in your "neat" example. The width of each column is equal to the maximum number of digits in that column (plus one space delimiter). Some may think it would look neater with a uniform column width (=maximum number of digits in entire table) and the code could easily be modified to do this.

```
' Convert integer table to string table
Dim astrTable() As String
ReDim astrTable(1 To UBound(multiplicationTable, 1), _
    1 To UBound(multiplicationTable, 2))
Dim intMaxDigitsInColumn As Integer
Dim intDigitsInThisNumber As Integer
For y = 1 To maxNum
    ' Determine width of column (= max number of digits)
    intMaxDigitsInColumn = 1
    For x = 1 To maxNum
        intDigitsInThisNumber = 1 + _
            Int(Log(multiplicationTable(x, y)) / Log(10#))
        If intDigitsInThisNumber > intMaxDigitsInColumn Then
            intMaxDigitsInColumn = intDigitsInThisNumber
        End If
    Next x

    ' Convert each table element into string of appropriate length
    For x = 1 To maxNum
        astrTable(x, y) = Space(intDigitsInThisNumber)
        Mid(astrTable(x, y), 1) = CStr(multiplicationTable(x, y))
    Next x
Next y

' Print the table with a space delimiter between columns
Dim strTable As String
strTable = ""
For x = 1 To maxNum
    For y = 1 To maxNum
        strTable = strTable & astrTable(x, y) & " "
    Next y
    strTable = strTable & vbCrLf
Next x
Debug.Print strTable
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! ^_^ Now I have an idea how to attack the problem. :)